# Ubuntu 20.04 stop to start in graphic mode. I can't access to my graphic environment anymore

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ubuntu-20.04

I am not a system engineer (I am a software developer) and I am experiencing this problem with a Linux Ubuntu 20.04 virtual machine.

Today, after that I installed Python (it is the last operation that I have done) my system stop to start in graphic mode. It start in console mode.

Using the grep command to show the **/vat/log/bootstrap.log** file content and filtering for error I am obtaining these error at system startup:

[image]

It also seems that networking have some problem: I can't download with wget anything or ping anything.

It could be the cause of my problem? What can I try to do to restore my graphic environment?

Comment: Python is already installed and a fundamental part of the OS. It's also a *specific* version that CAN'T be changed otherwise you break the entire OS which is what seems to have happened here. When and if you need different versions there are ways to work with them in contained environments (yes, there's some potentially "heavy" stuff to learn here but everything is easily searchable; AskUbuntu is littered with thousand of questions by user who made the exact same mistake). Solution: start over from a known good backup or redo the VM.

Comment: @ChanganAuto and there is nothing that I can try to do to restore my machine?

Comment: Everything you can try has no guarantee of success whatsoever and takes a lot more time and effort than just starting over. If you care to read about the aforementioned questions at AU you'll get the picture, more often than not the suggestion is reinstall. The fact is you already broke all the OS tools that could be used to fix it, namely `apt`, because they all depend on the specific python version the OS runs.

Comment: Can you start Gnome in the terminal ?    https://www.fosslinux.com/60208/start-gnome-desktop-from-command-line-in-debian.htm

Comment: The purpose of my question was to determine if Gnome can run. Certainly if not and as @ChanganAuto notes, you need to rebuild your VM unless you have a backup.